# Unity item database in XML

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

Im trying to create a item database for my game. I want it to contain all the items in game (weapons, consumables, armors, etc). But I want them all to inherit from a parent class called item. All the examples I have seen use a single item class and no inheritance.

Is there a way in XML to make my database in such a way that when I deserialize it, they all will be in the correct type? Weapon will be of type weapon, armors of type armor and etc.

My current XML and Item and Container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ItemCollection>
  <Items>
    <DatabaseItem name="Sword">
      <Damage>20</Damage>
    </DatabaseItem>
    <DatabaseItem name="Wand">
      <Damage>10</Damage>
    </DatabaseItem>
  </Items>
</ItemCollection>
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

[XmlRoot("itemCollection")]
public class ItemContainer
{
    [XmlArray("Items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("DatabaseItem")]
    public List<DatabaseItem> items = new List<DatabaseItem>();

    public static ItemContainer Load(string path)
    {
        TextAsset _xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemContainer));
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(_xml.text);
        ItemContainer items = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as ItemContainer;
        reader.Close();
        return items;
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;    
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class DatabaseItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("title")]
    public string title;

    [XmlAttribute("damage")]
    public float damage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the standard capabilities of the serializer.

Create the desired hierarchy of classes:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Sword))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Axe))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Helmet))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Shell))]
public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("title")]
    public string Title;
}

public class Weapon : Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("damage")]
    public float Damage;
}

public class Armor : Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("protection")]
    public float Protection;
}

public class Sword : Weapon { }
public class Axe : Weapon { }

public class Helmet : Armor { }
public class Shell : Armor { }
```

Important! Specify all the classes are descendants of the base class in attribute `XmlInclude`.

Create multiple instances of our classes and will add them to the container:

```
var sword = new Sword();
var axe = new Axe();
var helmet = new Helmet();
var shell = new Shell();

var container = new ItemContainer();
container.Items.Add(sword);
container.Items.Add(axe);
container.Items.Add(helmet);
container.Items.Add(shell);
```

Now after serialization the xml will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<itemCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Items>
        <DatabaseItem xsi:type="Sword" damage="0" />
        <DatabaseItem xsi:type="Axe" damage="0" />
        <DatabaseItem xsi:type="Helmet" protection="0" />
        <DatabaseItem xsi:type="Shell" protection="0" />
    </Items>
</itemCollection>
```

Deserialization will correctly create instances of the desired classes.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could add an attribute which specifies the type. So your XML would look more like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ItemCollection>
  <Items>
    <DatabaseItem title="Sword">
      <damage>20</damage>
      <type>sword</type>  <-- New
    </DatabaseItem>
    <DatabaseItem title="Wand">
      <damage>10</damage>
      <type>wand</type>   <-- New
    </DatabaseItem>
  </Items>
</ItemCollection>
```

You then make a factory with is responsible for creating items from `DatabaseItem`. So you might call something like `ItemFactory.Create(DatabaseItem item)` and it will return an instance of that item. All of the code you need to make items will be in there and then you just hand out the new items as they are needed.

With the `type` variable you should have enough information for the system to infer what it has to make and the rest of the values are specific to just that items type, So armour doesn't need `damage` and so on.

If you want to keep everything clean/organised you could add serialise and deserialise methods to every item class so that all the factory has to do is look at the type and call the deserialize method for the relevant class which then looks at all the other information that it has available. This has the benefit of keeping all the code that is needed for a type together so you don't then have to figure out where the hell the creation code for helmets is when you add a new attribute to it...

You could then do the same thing with serialisation in order to keep the amount of text needed per item to only what is actually relevant (shoes likely won't need a damage attribute, etc.) But I don't know what your setup is, so for all i know you have an external tool which you use for serialisation...